# Operation is not allowed when object is closed

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

This is my complete code. I was able to run the code once and get the record sets export to excel, but I can't do a different operation the second time.

It looks like after the record set is closed once, its not opening again. When I search second time it giving me the above error *3704*.

Basically I have a form with three text boxes to search the database and then export the record sets to excel.

I might be missing something simple as I am not an experienced programmer.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub search_Click()

    Dim cn As Object

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Dim strSql As String


    Dim strConnection As String

    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWb As Object
    Dim xlWs As Object

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset


    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\Users\e3017764\Desktop\Master.accdb"

    cn.Open strConnection


    If (skill.Value = "" And location.Value = "" And project.Value = "") Then

        MsgBox "Please Enter Atleast one criteria"


    ElseIf (skill.Value <> "" And location.Value = "" And project.Value = "") Then

        strSql = "SELECT [Ecode/LC Code],[Resource Name],Project,Location FROM [Resource Details] WHERE [Primary Skills] = '" & skill.Value & "'"

        rs.Open strSql, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic


    ElseIf (skill.Value = "" And location.Value = "" And project.Value <> "") Then

        strSql = "SELECT [Ecode/LC Code],[Resource Name],Project,Location FROM [Resource Details] WHERE Project = '" & project.Value & "'"

        rs.Open strSql, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic


    ElseIf (skill.Value = "" And location.Value <> "" And project.Value = "") Then

        strSql = "SELECT [Ecode/LC Code],[Resource Name],Project,Location FROM [Resource Details] WHERE Location = '" & location.Value & "'"

        rs.Open strSql, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic


    ElseIf (skill.Value <> "" And project.Value <> "" And location.Value = "") Then

        strSql = "SELECT [Ecode/LC Code],[Resource Name],Project,Location FROM [Resource Details] WHERE [Primary Skills] = '" & skill.Value & "' AND Project = '" & project.Value & "'"

        rs.Open strSql, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic


    ElseIf (skill.Value <> "" And project.Value = "" And location.Value <> "") Then

        strSql = "SELECT [Ecode/LC Code],[Resource Name],Project,Location FROM [Resource Details] WHERE [Primary Skills] = '" & skill.Value & "' AND Location = '" & location.Value & "'"

        rs.Open strSql, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic


    ElseIf (skill.Value = "" And project.Value <> "" And location.Value <> "") Then

        strSql = "SELECT [Ecode/LC Code],[Resource Name],Project,Location FROM [Resource Details] WHERE Project = '" & project.Value & "' AND Location = '" & location.Value & "'"

        rs.Open strSql, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic


    ElseIf (skill.Value <> "" And project.Value <> "" And location.Value <> "") Then

        rs.Open

        strSql = "SELECT [Ecode/LC Code],[Resource Name],Project,Location FROM [Resource Details] WHERE [Primary Skills] = '" & skill.Value & "' AND Project = '" & project.Value & "' AND Location = '" & location.Value & "'"

        rs.Open strSql, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

    End If

    MsgBox " Total Records Matched " & rs.RecordCount

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    Set xlWs = xlWb.Worksheets("Sheet1")


    xlApp.Visible = True
    xlApp.UserControl = True

    xlWs.Cells(1, 1).Value = "E Code"
    xlWs.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Name"
    xlWs.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Project"
    xlWs.Cells(1, 4).Value = "Location"

    xlWs.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

    xlApp.Selection.CurrentRegion.Columns.AutoFit
    xlApp.Selection.CurrentRegion.Rows.AutoFit


    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I would change cn be an an ADODBConnection object rather than just an object. Then set the cursorlocationtype to be client. Then open the connection and see if that helps

Comment: You can't run the same code twice? Or different code? Which line produces the error?

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your reply, i just tried that but still getting the same error. its little annyoing why it works for the first time and throws error the second time.

Comment: hey dick, I have a form with 3 text boxes to enter the search criteria, I enter one n then click search, which perfectly gives me the result, then if I erase it and search with another criteria it thorws error. if i close the db then opn it again it works fine for the first search but second search gives me the same error. MsgBox " Total Records Matched " & rs.RecordCount  that lines give me error.

Comment: Remove this `rs.Open`.

Comment: hi JLILI, do you want me to try run sql query with execute?

Comment: It seems like all the `if` and `elseif` statements get skipped.  You could step through the 2nd time or add an `Else` statement with a `debug.print` or `msgbox` to see if the code ends up there.  Maybe you have a condition that doesn't get met when testing?

Comment: Does it run for a certain time and then come up with the message?

Comment: every time it runs for the first time, I assume that after first time going thru all the code, it reaches the final close statements and the object might be closed. but then i search for 2nd time probobly the closed object isnt getting opened again even if I do that in every else if loop.

Comment: How are you setting `skill.value`, `location.value` and `project.value`?

Comment: Is that code and the form you mentioned contained in `Master.accdb`?

Comment: Also change `currentproject.connection` to `cn`

Comment: @HansUp yes, Sam they come from the input form, where u enter the criteria to search the DB.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Sobigen that none of your IFs are true the second time around. Maybe. Anyway, I think if you simplify the IFs, you might see the answer more quickly.  Here's a rewrite to consider

```
Private Sub search_Click()

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sSql As String
    Dim aWhere() As String
    Dim lWhereCnt As Long
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWs As Object

    'This never changes, so make it a constant
    Const sSELECT As String = "SELECT [Ecode/LC Code],[Resource Name],Project,Location FROM [Resource Details] WHERE "

    'put each piece of your where clause in an array
    If Len(Me.skill.Value) > 0 Then
        lWhereCnt = lWhereCnt + 1
        ReDim Preserve aWhere(1 To lWhereCnt)
        aWhere(lWhereCnt) = "[Primary Skills] = '" & Me.skill.Value & "'"
    End If

    If Len(Me.location.Value) > 0 Then
        lWhereCnt = lWhereCnt + 1
        ReDim Preserve aWhere(1 To lWhereCnt)
        aWhere(lWhereCnt) = "[Location] = '" & Me.location.Value & "'"
    End If

    If Len(Me.project.Value) > 0 Then
        lWhereCnt = lWhereCnt + 1
        ReDim Preserve aWhere(1 To lWhereCnt)
        aWhere(lWhereCnt) = "[Project] = '" & Me.project.Value & "'"
    End If

    'If there's at least one criterion
    If lWhereCnt > 0 Then

        'build the sql and execute it
        sSql = sSELECT & Join(aWhere, " And ") & ";"
        Set rs = CurrentProject.Connection.Execute(sSql)

        'if at least one record is returned put it in excel
        If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
            Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            Set xlWs = xlApp.Workbooks.Add.worksheets(1)

            xlApp.Visible = True
            xlApp.UserControl = True

            xlWs.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value = Split("E Code,Name,Project,Location", ",")
            xlWs.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

            xlApp.Selection.CurrentRegion.Columns.AutoFit
            xlApp.Selection.CurrentRegion.Rows.AutoFit


            rs.Close
            Set rs = Nothing
        Else
            'if no records are return, take a look at the sql statement to see why
            MsgBox sSql
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox "Please Enter Atleast one criteria"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you all for help, as expected this simple fix did the trick.after each search operation i just reset all the three text boxes back to empty..now the IFs do execute and get me result everytime. I came to work today fresh this morning and was able to figure out this trick.. "fresh minds, fresh ideas" thank you all.